# React App as Application in IIS doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iis, create-react-app

I have created a React application **OptionsReact** using typescript and create-react-app. 
Then I build the application by running

```
npm run build
```

I create in IIS a **Website OptionsReact** and point it to the build folder, application works and I can see it in the browser.

But when I create an **Application OptionsReact** under an existing Website, the page in the browser is blank, it seems as if the server doesn't run javascript.

any ideas how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To host react application under the site in iis you could follow the below steps:

1)create an application in iis with the build folder.

[image]

2)open the index.html page which is located at the build folder.

[image]

3)convert all the links as below:

Convert all absolute links to relative ones.

```
<link href="/static/css/main.584f321a.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="./static/css/main.584f321a.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

4)assign the iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site and application root folder (e.g. app2)

5)refresh the site after doing changes and browse the site.

[image]

Comment: I checked index.html, all links have a dot in front of the uri. thanks anyway