# vueApp as Application in IIS doesn't work

Tags: .net, vue.js, iis

I created a .Net Vue app everything works fine in VisualStudio but when I want to publish it in IIS like an application of default web site (port 80) it doesnt work. If I do it like a new web site it does correctly.

[image]

[image]

It looks like doesnt find "dist" path of the proyect, beacuse in prduction server got the next errors but really dont kwon where to begin to search a solution:

[image]

Here is part of my startup file where I THINK is the mistake

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "clientapp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", port:8080);
                }
            });
        }
```

I tried to specify the full path of the dist path.
I had publish like a website before with everything working fine but never as an app of a website.

Really apreciate any help.

Comment: From the description, I understand that if you host the site as a new site then it work fine but if you host it as an application then it is not working. Please show what exact error you are seeing in the browser? what's the site binding when you host as application and whats the site binding when you host it as separate site? also Show, what exact URL you are using in browser to access both?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I was making tests and determine the problem is in binding/routes. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRbfvdx8v4g and again, everything works fine as website but not like an application. In index file I wrote the entire path of href and src elements and seems like explorer now can find them but the site is in blank. Also I follow this question with any difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002694/react-app-as-application-in-iis-doesnt-work

Comment: You could try to check the root of the site. It could be possible that your application is finding the root of localhost and not able to find the resources. You could make tests with the relative path. Further, please share the screenshot of the browser error.